# Java HtmlCleaner cleans "_" (underscore) of attributes

Tags: java, html, htmlcleaner

I am using http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/.

My problem is that Input html has:

```
<div _showid="asd" >
```

Output is :

```
<div showid="asd" >
```

I want to prevent to remove "_" from attributes.

Comment: Why do you want the "_" there? What's wrong with removing it

Comment: If the underline is being added to resolve attribute name conflicts, why not add a further character? For example, use the prefix `x_`, instead of a single `_`

Comment: Input html is outer source. It is not in my control. I just parse it. But before parsing I have to clean it. So I can not add a prefix @munyul. I try to get the tags with "_showid" attribute and it results empty because of HtmlCleaner removes "_"